# How to get a list of files by date order in WinRT/Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to get a list of files in date order in a Metro App in C#

I thought this code should do it,

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, new[] { ".xml" });
queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Recent", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

StorageFileQueryResult query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

but this gives me the following error:

> WinRT information: The requested enumeration option is not available
>   for this folder because it is not within a library or homegroup. Only folders within a library or a homegroup support all enumeration options.

Is there a way to get a list of files in date order when reading files from directories inside the Local folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recover the files and then use LINQ to Objects to perform the sorting for you.